# how to make rain water pile over text and pouring on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the rain flow over "my text"? I have this code which you can see in my JSFiddle:

```
function strop(cleft, ctop, d) {
    var drop = document.createElement('div');
    drop.className = 'punct';
    drop.style.left = cleft + 'px';
    drop.style.top = ctop + 'px';
    drop.id = d;
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(drop);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35h2Q/23/

The raining starts after the start button at the bottom is clicked.

I am trying to make the rain effect and what suddenly came to mind was "why not make the rain flow pile an pouring the text?". But I have tried everything to make the rain pile flow over the text but I have had no success.

I did some research and there may be some laws of physics which make it possible. Any ideas how I can do that? Have you any further suggestions to improve the animation?Thank you.

Comment: Going from `div`-based animation to `canvas`-based animation (like http://fabricjs.com/demos/ or http://threejs.org/examples/ would be another improvement)

Answer (score 1):

Set `z-index: 1` on the rain drop css rule

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35h2Q/22/